# Get map of field api and help text

Tags: apex, api

Is there a way to retrieve field API vs help text map or get the help text for fields.

```
String Field_Name=SObject.Field__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
 for(String fP: valuemap.keySet()){
                system.debug('fP'+fP);
                Object 
          helpText=Account.fP.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
                Object value = sc.get(fP); 
                mapObj.put(fP, String.valueOf(value));
            }
```

valuemap.keySet() is having the api name which i am iterating.
Giving error "Variable does not exist: Account.fP"

Comment: It looks like you know the method [`getInlineHelpText()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe), which is how you obtain this data point. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: yes i can get the help text of perticular field but i have to create a map of api name and help text and i dont want to put getDescribe inside the for loop while checking keyset from other map to get the key as api and value as helptext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to start from the field map and describe the fields:

```
Map<String, String> helpTexts = new Map<String, String>();
for(SObjectField field: SobjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()) {
    DescribeFieldResult des = field.getDescribe();
    helpTexts.put(des.getName(), des.getInlineHelpText());
}
```